# Java Spring MVC can't start app on Heroku. Error H10 (can't find webapp runner)

Tags: java, spring, maven, heroku

I am trying to run my app on Heroku but it doesn't work. From logs I can see the below:

> 2016-01-18T13:38:31.621218+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2016-01-18T13:38:48.101117+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Unable to
> access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner-8.0.30.1.jar
>
> 2016-01-18T13:38:48.100249+00:00 app[web.1]: Setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS
> defaults based on dyno size. Custom settings will override them.
>
> 2016-01-18T13:38:48.700243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from
> starting to crashed 2016-01-18T13:43:12.241285+00:00 heroku[router]:
> at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
> host=macfol.herokuapp.com
> request_id=c6418015-843d-4f5a-8dde-83130e94a7c6 fwd="159.220.74.5"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I have been unsuccessfully trying to modify both pom.xml as well as procfile in order that Heroku will finally find that .jar.

There is the procfile:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner-8.0.30.1.jar --target/kamienica
```

And the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>kamienica</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>Kamienica</name>

    <properties>
        <springframework.version>4.0.6.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>5.1.31</mysql.version>
        <joda-time.version>2.3</joda-time.version>
        <testng.version>6.9.4</testng.version>
        <mockito.version>1.10.19</mockito.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.187</h2.version>
        <dbunit.version>2.2</dbunit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda-Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>${joda-time.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- To map JodaTime with database type -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jadira.usertype</groupId>
            <artifactId>usertype.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.CR1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>${testng.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dbunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>dbunit</artifactId>
            <version>${dbunit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for rest -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.30.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.springsource.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                        <warName>Kamienica</warName>
                        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <artifactItems>
                                    <artifactItem>
                                        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                        <version>8.0.24.0</version>
                                        <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                    </artifactItem>
                                </artifactItems>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <finalName>Kamienica</finalName>
    </build>
    <artifactId>Kamienica</artifactId>
</project>
```

The "missing" jar can be found in maven dependencies.

Appreciate your help

**EDIT**
The procfile is now:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port
> $PORT target/kamienica.war

No result...

**EDIT 2**

There is some progress as it crashes elsewhere  ;)

[image]

**EDIT 3**
It's working! Thank you all for making this possible. Finally my app is there. It took me 12 months to reach this point.
Thank you again! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First Remove the  start `<pluginManagement>` and end `<pluginManagement/>` tags in `pom.xml` (Do not delete the content inside it). By including this, the `dependency` directory and the `webapp-runner-8.0.30.1.jar` will not be created and the application is getting crashed when executing the java command.
2. Change the `finalName` tag to `<finalName>kamienica</finalName>` . Right now you have the capital letter(`K`) in the `<finalName>...</finalName>` tag. Change it to small letter as you named it in `web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/kamienica.war`
3. Change the name to `<warName>kamienica</warName>` in `maven-war-plugin` plugin

   ```
              <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>2.6</version>
                   <configuration>
                       <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                       <warName>kamienica</warName>
                       <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                   </configuration>
               </plugin>
   ```

Comment: Thank you!!! It's working. 12 months of developing my first app and now it's there! Thank you!!

Comment: Thank you. I was facing the same issue. Its working now

Answer (score 3):

Your `destFileName` is `webapp-runner.jar` but your referencing to another jar in your `Procfile`:

```
web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner-8.0.30.1.jar --target/kamienica
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                 Version is redundant
```

Use this instead:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/Kamienica.war
```

Comment: `Kamienica` in `kamienica.war` should be starts with a uppercase letter

Comment: As @TimeTravel said, remove the `pluginManagement` tags