# Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, heroku

I am trying to configure the Procfile file for Heroku platform to run the application locally. I am trying to run a Tomcat-based Java Web Application.

In the tutorial they say:

```
To build your app locally do this:
Use the Git Bash application to open a command shell on Windows.
$ mvn clean install
$ heroku local web
```

I am in the project directory and after `mvn clean install` I receive

> `BUILD SUCCESS`

The problem is when I run: `heroku local web`
I receive `[WARN] No ENV file found
 web.1 |  Error: Could not find or load main class $JAVA_OPTS`

My Procfile has 1 line:

> web:    java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar
>   --port $PORT target/*.war

I am using Windows. I saw a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25734085/6326888) on stack and they were saying that the code on Windows in the Procfile is different. It should look something like this(my creation):

> web:    java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar target\dependency\webapp-runner.jar
>   --port %PORT% target*.war

I have to create a folder called "dependency" in the target folder? because I don't have webbapp-runner.jar in my project and I don't understand what should I do.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.rares</groupId>
<artifactId>first-web-application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
        <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
        <version>8.5.11.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Should I add the webapp-runner as a plugin?

Comment: did you try other solutions from the same post you've shared? Like `web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -cp target\classes;"target\dependency\*"  Main`. You can follow [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java#the-procfile)

Comment: what it is my Main class? I have just a LoginController java class and Login Service ..a class for my controller with a method

Comment: @ProhIsMetal Service class should be the one. Ideally the class that you want to startup your application from.

Comment: I will post later the logs with the errors when I try to upload it to heroku. But I can t basicaly make a local server for the app because of this error...I want to test it local because when I run the application with tomcat in eclipse I can see at localhost:8080/login what I want. I want to mention that my LoginService class has just 1 method isTrue which return true or false. Are you sure if that can fix the problem?

Comment: If you could vote the question it would be great! Maybe someone knows a better solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add webapp-runner to your `pom.xml` like this:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals><goal>copy</goal></goals>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactItems>
                        <artifactItem>
                            <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                            <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                            <version>8.5.11.2</version>
                            <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                        </artifactItem>
                    </artifactItems>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Then your `Procfile` can look like this:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port $PORT target/*.war
```

And your `Procfile.windows` can look (something) like this:

```
web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar target\dependency\webapp-runner.jar --port %PORT% target\*.war
```

For more information see [Deploying Tomcat-based Java Web Applications with Webapp Runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner).

Comment: Please use [uptodate versions of plugins](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) and not so ancient versions...

Comment: I have to define somewhere $JAVA_OPTS?

Comment: When I run :  mvn package
I receive build succes and after java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war I receive: error unable to access jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar

Answer (score 1):

So I read alot of posts on stackoverflow about this error + tutorials on Heroku and didn't find a solution but I made a improvement. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34877111/6326888) and deleted the start `<pluginManagement>` and end `<pluginManagement/>` tags in `pom.xml` and now the `dependency` directory and the `webapp-runner-8.0.30.1.jar` are created. 
My application is working because if I run my app in Eclipse with Tomcat  I can go to localhost:8080/login and I can see my website.
When I run :

> mvn package

I receive `build succes` and after that I run in cmd

> java -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar target/*.war

I receive: `error invalid or corrupt jarfile target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar`

Here is my Procfile:

> web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar target/dependency/webapp-runner.jar --port
>   $PORT target/*.war

Here is my Procfile.windows:

> web: java %JAVA_OPTS% -jar target\dependency\webapp-runner.jar --port %PORT% target*.war

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.rares</groupId>
<artifactId>first-web-application</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <contextReloadable>true</contextReloadable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.github.jsimone</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>webapp-runner</artifactId>
                                    <version>8.5.11.2</version>
                                    <destFileName>webapp-runner.jar</destFileName>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```